# mvn clean install - pljava deployment error - require assistance

Tags: maven, pljava

I am getting the below error while trying to do Mvn Clean Install .. what should be done here- this is preventing the installation of the Pl java - pls assist

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.9.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.9.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.9.1/maven-site-plugin-3.9.1.pom: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Network/firewall error .. `repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known -`...